# Is it copyright infringement if I make a clone of a game for educational purposes, and upload it on github?

Tags: copyright, educational-games

Pacman and Snake Xenzia are common examples, and many universities have programming assignments where you recreate parts of a game (or even the entire game) without copying any of the artwork and design, etc. Is it okay to upload something like this (which was NOT written as a part of a course) under a personal profile on Github? Or will you necessarily have nothing to show for embarking on a project such as this one?

Comment: If you build it from scratch with free tools, frameworks and sources  and don't actually call it `pacman` and `snake xenzia`, which are trademarks, it should be fine.

Comment: There are tons of these questions.